# How to add embeds in Discord V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm new to javascript and programming.
I'm trying to add embeds to my commands but I'm struggling quite badly.
This is what my code looks like:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {

        if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '?help') {
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('This is a test Embed.')
            .setURL('https://example.com')
            .setAuthor('example')
            .setDescription('This is a test Description which we will see.')
            .setColor('#FF2D00')
            .setThumbnail('https://example.png')
            .setImage('https://example.png')
            .setFooter('This is a example footer', 'https://example.png')
            .addFields({
              name: 'Test Number 1',
              value: 'This is a example value',
              inline: true
            }, {
              name: 'Test Number 2',
              value: 'This is a example value',
              inline: true
            }, {
              name: 'Test Number 3',
              value: 'This is a example value'
            }, {
              name: 'Test Number 4',
              value: 'This is a example value'
            })
            .setTimestamp();

          message.channel.send(embed);
        }
```

And basically I keep getting an error from my console saying that: `MessageEmbed` is undefined and I don't know why.

(I'm really new to programming so sorry if this question is a bot question.)

Comment: What value is the `Discord` variable here? Is it `const Discord = require('discord.js')`?

Comment: ``const { Client, CategoryChannel, Discord } = require('discord.js')`` @MarcosCarvalho

Comment: @Mystik I would `const Discord = require("discord.js")` and `const client = new Discord.Client()` separately for the best results.

Comment: Levi_OP is right. `MessageEmbed` is undefined because you aren't bringing it in from discord.js, which has the class you're looking for.

Comment: @levi_op Ok I'll try that. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Let me know if it works or doesn’t, and please mark it as the answer if it does

Comment: @Levi_OP here are all my variables:
``const Discord = require("discord.js") 
const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION']});
const db = require ('./database');
const Ticket = require('./models/Ticket');
const TicketConfig = require('./models/TicketConfig');
``

Comment: ok so what? did it work?

Comment: @Levi_O no, it just throw an error: client is undefined.
the one i pasted above is all my varibles/the original one.
Const Discord = require ('Discord.js') and
const client = new Discord.client didnt work

Comment: It’s `new Discord.Client()` not just `new client`

Comment: still doest work, can you see my reply below to the other guy. 
I tried his way and i got that error from node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the library imported:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

Or do it like so:

```
const { Client, CategoryChannel, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
```

Comment: libary is imported already, 
``const { Client, CategoryChannel, Discord } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION']});
const db = require ('./database');
const Ticket = require('./models/Ticket');
const TicketConfig = require('./models/TicketConfig');
`` 
If i change it it will mess up my code but i guess i can fix it.

Comment: discord.js must be imported like the following: `const Discord = require("discord.js)`.
If you want to import it with the destructuring-syntax you have to do it like so: `const { Client, CategoryChannel, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")`.

Comment: i tried that, but i just another error:
``(node:12516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of 
undefined``